# Launch an exernal program with Python, but without waiting

Tags: python

When I use

```
os.system('notepad.exe')
```

the Python script will only be finished once the notepad window is closed.
How to prevent Python from waiting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe"])
```

Comment: thank you very much.
Is there a way to bring this new process as main current window (focus) ?

Comment: The [subprocess docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) show you how

Comment: thanks @tdelaney, but I don't find something related to `focus` in this doc.

Comment: @Basj - I think the SW_SHOWNORMAL flag does it. I did a bit of testing, and it looks like that's the default anyway. If I run `subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe"])`, it comes up on top and has the focus.

Comment: Yes but when we launch a process that can only be launched once (one instance), and this process is running in background, then it doesn't show

Comment: A last question @tdelaney, how do you do a `Popen` with SW_SHOWNORMAL enabled ?

Comment: @Basj - My bad, SW_SHOWNORMAL is from ShellExecute - but it should work from the background also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python win32 extensions to call ShellExecute which lets you grab focus, even if the calling script has been minimized. I think windows has registry settings that modify how this works, so your mileage may vary, but here's an example that you can run from the command line, and then minimize the command window.

```
import win32api
import time

print "minimize this window for test..."
time.sleep(5)
win32api.ShellExecute(None, "open", "notepad.exe", "somefile.txt", None, 5)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume you are on windows since you are trying to start notpad.exe as an example.

```
os.system('start notepad.exe')
```